# Delete multiple rows using checkbox from mysql table using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I wanted a row or multiple rows to be deleted when they are selected via check boxes. But it doesn't seem to delete anything even if I select.

Here's what I come up with:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","annualdb");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM asean_japan WHERE agency='Air'");

if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
  $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];

  for($i=0;$i<count((array)$checkbox);$i++) {
    $del_id = $checkbox[$i];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM asean_japan WHERE id='$del_id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
  }
// if successful, refresh same page 
if($result) {
  echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=index.php\">";
}
}
?>
<table class='page'>
  <tr>
    <th>Select</th>
    <th>Agency</th>
    <th>FileName</th>
    <th>FileType</th>
    <th>Date Received</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  ?>
  <tr>
    <td align='center' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><input name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' value='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['agency']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['filename']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['filetype']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
    <td><a target='_blank' href='../annual/indicators/" <?php echo $row['filename']; ?>"'>OPEN</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<?php
}
?>
<tr>
  <td colspan="4" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="delete" type="submit" value="Delete"></td>
</tr>
<?php
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Is there a problem with my checkbox or the input=delete maybe?

Comment: Did you do Debugging? i.e Are you getting anything in $_POST['checkbox']? Is your $del_id getting specific selected checkbox value? whenever you ask a question please do debug so the actual problem will uncover

Comment: Yes I tried debugging, no error appears. But no results as well. it does not delete anything

Answer (score 1):

first you need to close table tag outside the while loop and then you need to check onclick your data post or not to target url [click here this will help you](https://www.phpzag.com/delete-multiple-rows-with-checkbox-using-jquery-php-mysql/)

Answer (score 0):

```php
    foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $key =>$val) {
        if($val!='') {
             $sql = "DELETE FROM asean_japan WHERE id='$val'";
             $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);  
        }
    }
```

Comment: i think you missed the form tag

Comment: new to php but I understand this code deletes row when checkbox are not empty or checked right? But still it doesn't do anything. Can't figure out why

Comment: <form name="test" id="test" method="post"><table>.......</table>SUBMIT BUTTON</form>

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it. Additionally, have a look at SQL injections - your code is highly vulnerable and should not be used in production!